# What ancient Roman(s) wished houses were made of transparent walls?

Tags: ancient-rome, architecture, reference

What ancient Roman(s) wished houses were made of transparent walls?

source:
St. Joseph Cafasso's [*The Priest: The Man of God: His Dignity and Duties*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6013) [p. 50](https://books.google.com/books?id=0ty7CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT50):

> a Roman of ancient times wished his house to be made—with transparent walls, so that everyone outside can see what is being done inside.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Well, I only have one source, the one I cited. I can't find any others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be related to a tale told of Domitian, who was reacting to a prophecy concerning his death. From [*The History of the Roman Emperors: From Augustus to Constantine*, Volume 6](https://books.google.com/books?id=gPlAAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA417&dq=roman%20ruler%20transparent%20walls&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjb3qbtzvTlAhUMHzQIHTQiCAoQ6AEwAXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q&f=false) ([original French](https://books.google.com/books?id=nKiF72WNkWYC&pg=PA98)) by Jean Baptiste Louis Crevier (emphasis mine)

> He took a farther precaution to guard against any unexpected attack. A
>   stone was found in Nero's time in some quarries in Cappadocia of a
>   very extraordinary nature hard as marble and ***at the same time
>   transparent*** or rather luminous for according to Pliny the naturalist.
>   Nero built a temple of this stone into which one could see distinctly
>   when all the doors were shut. Domitian to turn this discovery to the
>   best advantage he could and prevent any one from coming behind him
>   without being perceived ***had all the walls of the portico's where he
>   used to walk cased with this stone*** so suitable to his views.

You can see what Pliny had to say concerning this transparent stone in [Natural Histories, BOOK XXXVI. THE NATURAL HISTORY OF STONES.](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0137%3Abook%3D36)

> CHAP. 46.—PHENGITES. During the reign of Nero, there was a stone found
>   in Cappadocia, as hard as marble, white, and transparent even in those
>   parts where red veins were to be seen upon it; a property which has
>   obtained for it the name of "phengites." It was with this stone
>   that Nero rebuilt the Temple of Fortune, surnamed Seia, originally
>   consecrated by King Servius, enclosing it within the precincts of his
>   Golden Palace. Hence it was that, even when the doors were closed,
>   there was light in the interior during the day; not transmitted from
>   without, as would be the case through a medium of specular-stone, but
>   having all the appearance of being enclosed within the building. 
>   In
>   Arabia, too, according to Juba, there is a stone, transparent like
>   glass, which is used for the same purposes as specular-stone.